# hadoop streaming failed with error code 1..trying rmr(Rhadoop--R package) with Datastax cassandra

Tags: r, git, github, datastax-enterprise, rhadoop

I need a clarification regarding rmr+rhdfs(Rhadoop) with Datastax cassandra(CFS).
Currently all the functions in rhdfs and rmr(to.dfs(),from.dfs()) are working.

But When I try to run mapreduce(), below error occurs:

streaming command failed!.Hadoop streaming failed with error code 1.

plus it is not at all creating any logs in the jobtracker.no stderr.
Kindly help me to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

rmr 3.1.0 is compatible with Apache Hadoop 2.2.0

https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2/blob/master/docs/compatibility.md

DSE use a customized Hadoop 1.0.4, so it tells why mapreduce() fails for your testing.

One work around is to set up your own hadooop cluster and replace HDFS with CFS